# Using Azure Logic App HTTP Action with many endpoints

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-http-trigger

I'm using an HTTP Action inside an Azure Logic App. I want to send requests to an adress [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) with many endpoints (\1, \2 ..).

I don't want to create an HTTP Action for every endpoint, so is there any way to specify all those endpoints in a file and use a kind of lood in that action?

Thank you

Comment: you could always create an array parameter and loop through it.

Comment: how could I do that?

Comment: documentation for parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-parameters-workflows?tabs=consumption#define-use-and-edit-parameters

Comment: documentation for loop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Multiples end points**
mydomain dot com /Java, /Csharp, / Js

You follow blew steps.

1. Create array object.

```json
[
{"language":"Java","Book":"P.K Sharma"},
{"language":"CSharp","Book":"S.K Sharma"},
{"language":"JS","Book":"J.K Sharma"}
]
```

2. Initialize variable.
3. Create variable.
   [image]
4. For each loop
   [image]
5. Add action in for each loop.
   [image]
6. Http action
   [image]

More information on [Call, trigger, or nest logic apps by using HTTPS endpoints in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint) by Microsoft Documents.